# make inner div inside not overlap outer div

Tags: html, css

I have the following image, but i need the blue part to be inside the white div. tried with overflow:hidden but doesn't work. how can i make it not to be visible and retain the border radius of the white div.

[image]

```
<div class="qrcode" style=" z-index: 1;display: block; margin: auto; text-align: center; height: 250px; width: 300px; border-radius: 4%; background-color: #ffffff;">
                <div class="brand" style=" background-color:rgb(0, 214, 255); height: 260px; width:50px;">

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: overflow:hidden worked for me on your code if you put it on the outer div. If you don't need that div to have interactive content you could just do border-left on that outer div to be blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow:hidden` is working you can see the below:

```html
<div class="qrcode" style=" z-index: 1;display: block; margin: auto; text-align: center; height: 250px; width: 300px; border-radius: 4%; background-color: #F7F7F7; overflow:hidden;">
                <div class="brand" style=" background-color:rgb(0, 214, 255); height: 260px; width:50px;">

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it didn't worked for me, could this be an issue with safari?

Comment: Effectively all browsers support overflow:hidden property. You can see it here https://caniuse.com/?search=overflow-hidden

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: hidden` does work though:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="qrcode" style=" z-index: 1;display: block; margin: auto; text-align: center; height: 250px; width: 300px; border-radius: 4%; background-color: #ffffff;overflow:hidden">
  <div class="brand" style=" background-color:rgb(0, 214, 255); height: 260px; width:50px;">

  </div>
</div>
```

it's better if you set the child height smaller though in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding `overflow-y: hidden` to your `qrcode` class